# Hook to Win32 API event to get notified when Desktop fully loads

Tags: windows, winapi, events, dwm

Imagine a scenario when a user is logged in and without signing out switches to another user. Then switches back. When switching back (because we never signed out), Windows will first display a black desktop then do some Window flickering (especially with 2 monitors), then finally re-arrange everything to the state that we left off. That flickering and re-arrangement takes some time (roughly 1 second).

What would be the most efficient way of getting a notification about Desktop being fully loaded? I need this because I want to call my specific function when the desktop is fully loaded.

One option is to hook to `WM_PAINT`, but I used Spy++ and I get 12 `WM_PAINT` events on desktop, so that won't be reliable. Anyone aware of another way?

Comment: I would recommend using doing an api trace / ETW trace and observing the messages being passed around. On top of that there are APIs specifically for [interacting with and hooking desktop creation/switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684303(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @JakeHeidt, actually I was just trying OpenInputDesktop. The thing is that the desktop is ready for Input, but the windows have not been arranged that. I have display duplication function that I need to call when everything on desktop has been arranged. If I call it sooner the display duplication does not work. If I put a Sleep for 2 seconds, it works. The thing is that while it is flickering, it is already accepting input, so this function returns successfully.

Comment: @JakeHeidt DwmFlush() from DWM API worked beautifully for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a much, much simpler solution. A call to to DwmFlush(). The function is part of Windows DWM api.

Here is a sample code that I tested and it actually worked with fast user switching in Windows 8.1:

```
while (true)
{
    HRESULT hr = DwmFlush();

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "TRUE" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FALSE" << std::endl;
    }

    Sleep(1000);

}
```